# Make a number of objects available to user

Tags: c++, oop, object

Say I built a `Note` (musical notes) class (`note.h`, `note.cpp`) and wanted to provide the user of my library with a set of most commonly used `Note` objects

```
Note a = Note('a');
Note b = Note('b');
Note c = Note('c');
...
```

If the user wanted to use an F sharp, he/she'd need to create an `Note('f','sharp')` object, but for the sake of simplicity, I want to provide the most common root notes as objects.

What would be possible (and the recommended) way to achieve this?

1) Using a header file with `extern` declarations and a corresponding implementation file? (Maybe even the `note.h`, `note.cpp` files?)

2) Providing static class methods like `Note Note::a() {return Note('a');}` etc. (although this approach would be to verbose for my taste...).

Other solutions?

Comment: Developing a library is most complex task (much more difficult than developing an app). There way too many variants and I doubt there is a "recommended" way. It depends on whole library design.

Comment: `enum`s seem to be made for that. (for the constructor's parameter, I mean)

Comment: You might be interested to have a look at the [_Flyweight Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If C++17 is available, and static initialization order is not an issue, I'd go with `inline` variables. If C++17 is not available, but static initialization order is still not an issue, I'd go with `extern` declarations and definitions in  .cpp file.

If there are issues of static initialization order, I'd go with little static helper functions, like yours.

Comment: May I suggest adding consexpr user-defined literal to the mix? It'd be a nice syntax `play("A#"_n + "Fb"_n, 1s);` :)

Comment: @YSC, you may, but I would not do this ))). The reason is I am tired of sudden ODR issues when completely unbeknownst to the code user those constexpr literals are becoming ODR-used.

Comment: Who would ?!?

Answer (score 4):

Go for [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)<sup>1</sup>:

```
Note operator "" _note(char const* value, std::size_t) { return Note{value}; }
```

This lets you write really nice things like:

```
play("A#"_note + "Fb"_note + "G"_note, 1s);
```

[Full example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edf30c8d1b349505)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> If `Note` qualifies, define a [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) operator.</sub>

Comment: Nice, I've never heard of that concept and will definitely dig deeper into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static member variable in your Note class. Perhaps a map with {note-type -> count} would be enough? You'll have to handle the counters in your constructors but it will be invisible to the user of your class. Then you could add static access methods for users to extract data. Remember to protect access to the static map if you or your users go multi-threaded.